# Is the IIS role necessary on a dedicated SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, iis

I haven't been able to find anything on this. I'm looking into only the bare necessities for a dedicated SQL server being used by a SharePoint farm.

Is the Web Server (IIS) role necessary for a dedicated SQL server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. IIS is only for serving up webpages. It should not be part of SQL Server, which uses tcp/ip, or named pipes to communicate with other servers.

Comment: Thanks! The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx) for the requirements echoes your answer. Accepted.